# Sudden jump and then a sudden drop in accuracy in neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

At the end of first epoch, in my models, the validation accuracy is higher than my training accuracy, for example training accuracy be 64% and validation accuracy be 88%. At the beginning of the next epoch, say after 100 iterations (since I am printing the results after each 100 iters), the training accuracy becomes equal to the validation accuracy that was at the end of the last epoch.

Again, at the end of the second epoch, the validation accuracy was 85%. And at the start of the 3rd epoch, the training accuracy became 85%.

And the loss hasn't decreased much at all.

Why does this happen?

And when this happens, the training accuracy stops increasing steadily (like it was doing in the previous epoch). And also another importatn thing to note is that the loss stops decreasing. Everything plateaus.
Whereas, the loss should have shown a decreasing tendency.

[image]

I don't understand the reason for this phenomenon. Any help will be appreciated.

1 epoch = 1000 iterations.
Values plotted every 100 iterations

**Why does the value of training accuracy in the current epoch follow the value of Validation accuracy in the last epoch?**